# Wifi penetration testing: Why aireplay-ng de-authentication does not work?

Tags: penetration-test, wifi, wpa2, dictionary, wpa2-psk

I am trying to pentest the security of the password of my wireless network. It is a `WPA2` with pre-shared-keys. My current computer is connected to the wifi router and I try to de-auth my own machine.

**Steps**

1. I created a monitoring interface:

   sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
2. Now I use airodump-ng to find the channel and MAC of the access point:

   sudo airodump-ng mon0
3. My access point has the channel 10 and the MAC `ACCESS_POINT_MAC`. I can record packets now:

   sudo airodump-ng -c 10 --bssid ACCESS_POINT_MAC mon0
4. I try now to deauthenticate my computer from the network with `aireplay-ng`, but it does not work:

   sudo aireplay-ng -0 1 -a ACCESS_POINT_MAC mon0

   13:50:47  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: ACCESS_POINT_MAC) on channel -1
   13:50:47  Couldn't determine current channel for mon0, you should either force the operation with --ignore-negative-one or apply a kernel patch
   Please specify an ESSID (-e).

- **Why doesn't the de-authentication with aireplay-ng work?**

---

**Update**
after feedback from @BadSkillz

I added `--ig` and `-e ssid_string` to my command. However, it could not find the BSSID:

```
14:11:56 Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: MAC_ADDRESS) on channel -1       
14:12:06 No such BSSID available.
```

At the same time I can find the MAC_ADDRESS|BSSID with `airodump-ng`. Moreover,
I tried to use another interface when specifying the channel:

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 10
```

resulting in `mon1`. Nevertheless, the `aireplay-ng` still does not look at a specific channel.

Comment: You also need to provide the mac for the client you want to deauth with the -c option, as described [here](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=deauthentication)

Comment: I added the `-c` to the command. Still it cannot find the BSSID.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and after some research I found that everything worked fine when I disabled the `wlan0` interface before running the attack.

To disable the `wlan0` interface, I used the following command:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

Then I tried the following command again:

```
aireplay-ng --deauth 1111 -a macadress-of-ap -c macadress-of-client mon0
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem with an RTL8812AU on Kali 2018. What fixed it for me was throwing a -D into the attack command line so it stops trying to automatically determine the channel and just does what you tell it to.

Comment: Totally my experience with RTL8812AU on Kali 2019! 
`-D` did the trick; Forcing to send those packets worked as a charm, without that flag the `AP detection` fails over and over throwing the OP's mentioned error. However the deauth worked nice as I can see my phone disconnecting but the capturing of the handshake didn't work. I was running the proper command with the channel and BSSID, same command that worked with other network adapters but now luck. @Nicodemus did you manage to capture the handshake following the `deauth`?

Comment: answering my own question from the above comment: for the `WPA handshake` capture to work I had to kill the `wpa_supplicant` process. Also not sure it matters but my `ifconfig wlan0 up` was run before so the card was enabled.

Answer (score 3):

It's looking at channel -1, try running aircrack with the following option: `--ignore-negative-one` or `--ig` as it said in the error you posted:

> 13:50:47  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: ACCESS_POINT_MAC) on channel -1
>
> 13:50:47  Couldn't determine current channel for mon0, you should either force the operation with --ignore-negative-one or apply a kernel patch

Comment: I added `--ig` and `-e ssid_string` to my command. However, it could not find the BSSID:
`14:11:56  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: MAC_ADDRESS) on channel -1
14:12:06  No such BSSID available.`

On the same time I can find the MAC_ADDRESS|BSSID with `airodump-ng`.

Comment: I tried to use another interface when specifying the channel: `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 10` resulting in `mon1`. Nevertheless, the `aireplay-ng` still does not look at a specific channel.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the above problem occurs when you are broadcasting the deauth packets with your attacking machine's `MAC` and not with your router's `MAC`.

So to solve it you should change the attacker WiFi interface's `MAC` address to the same as your router's `MAC`. (This is so because you can't change the `MAC` of `mon0` after it has been created.)
So do this:

- Disable `mon0`.
- Shut down wireless interface `ifconfig wlan0 down` (or whatever your interface is called).
- Set the attacker's `MAC` to your routers: `ifconfig wlan0 hw ether TARGET_MAC`.
- Reactivate interface, create new `mon0` and do your deauth attack. It should work now. (Also make sure replay the deauth packet 3-4 times as for some reason sometimes a single death just won't work.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unnecessary as aireplay already has the -h parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that existed on older kali versions. To deal with it either update to a newer kali or use the `--ignore-negative-one` switch. Killing some problematic services with the `airmon-ng check kill` has also been found helpful.

Even for newer versions you should lock your card to the desired channel. So sudo `airmon-ng stop monX` and then `sudo airmon-ng start wlanX YY` where X is the number of your interface and YY the number of the desired channel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your wireless card can do packet injection (check this by `aireplay-ng -9 <interface>`) and make sure at least one client should be connected with AP.
To avoid any problems during pentest:
`airmon-ng check kill`

Then issue command:
`airmon-ng start wlan0 <channel>` (you can find the AP channel by `airodump-ng wlan0`)
By doing this aireplay-ng will probe the only specified channel.

Now issue the following set of commands step by step.

1. `airodump-ng -c <channel> --bssid <BSSID OF AP> -w <directory_to_store_.cap file> <interface>`. Now the four files should be appeared in your directory.
2. Keep this terminal running and note the client's MAC.
3. Now to deauthenticate the client:

   `airelplay-ng -0 2 -a <AP MAC> -c <client's mac> <inteface>`

Now you should be able to deauthenticate the client and get WPA handhake on your former terminal screen.

If this doesn't help try `airmon-ng stop <interface>` and then `service network-manager start`. Then repeat all steps again.

P.S In my whole answer i used the word 'interface' for the 'interface on which wireless card is monitoring'.

Comment: The OP lists all of these "step by step" commands in the question ....

Comment: @schroeder OP was missing airmon-ng check kill and he was unable to find even  bssid. I mean how? So I answered from very beginning to deauthentication process.

Comment: The only thing you have added was the `check kill` but this was included in another answer. I'm really not sure how this answer adds anything.

Comment: @schroeder I was trying to indent the code but I will do it later.

Comment: The problem is not with the indenting but with the content - there is nothing new in your answer that isn't stated by the OP or in other answers.

Comment: @schroeder again I am telling, I have nothing new to add to my answer.I was just indenting the code so that it look readable.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the first wlan0 using

```
ifconfig wlan0mon down
```

Then run

```
iwconfig wlan0mon channel X
```

where X is channel of AP which you want to attack.
Then just start interface again with

```
ifconfig wlan0mon up.
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

> There are many possible root causes of this problem:
>
> - The wireless card is set to a channel which is different from the AP. Solution: Use iwconfig and confirm the card is set to the same
>     channel as the AP.
> - The card is scanning channels. Solution: Start airodump-ng with the “-c” or “–channel” parameter and set it to the same channel as the
>     AP.
> - The ESSID is wrong. Solution: Enter the correct value. If if contains spaces or special characters then enclose it in quotes. For
>     the complete details, see this FAQ entry.
> - The BSSID is wrong. Solution: Enter the correct value.
> - You are too far away from the AP and are not receiving any beacons. Solution: You can use tcpdump and/or airodump-ng to confirm
>     you are in fact receiving beacons for the AP. If not, move closer.
> - You are not receiving beacons for the AP: Solution: Use “tcpdump -n -vvv -e -s0 -i ” to confirm you are receiving beacons. Assuming you have dealt with with potential problems above,
>     it could be the drivers or you have not put the card into monitor
>     mode.

https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=aireplay-ng#waiting_for_beacon_frame

Answer (score -1):

Try to stop Networkmanager:

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager stop
```

Comment: If there were a program interfering with the use of `wlan0`, `airmon-ng` would have warned about it.