# Unassociated MACs in airodump-ng display

Tags: airodump-ng

[image]

What are the extra MACs in `airodump` display that are not real associated adapters? What are they for?  There are only 4 things connected to this router - (verified by viewing router dhcp list)  but there are over 15 MACs displayed by `airodump-ng`.  I see the actual MACs have higher ACK times.

Comment: Associated stations of other access points in your neighbour listening on the same channel on which you are. Use this to only capture your stations `airodump-ng -c 9 --bssid 00:14:6C:7E:40:80 -w psk wlan0mon`

Comment: some reason when i use channel switch -c airodump still displays "fixed channel wlan0mon:...." appears to still scan thru channels 1-12 - and your explanation verifies it is indeed still scanning and listing other access points.....likely why im having trouble capturing handskake.....i will try "airmon-ng start wlan0 3" to see if that locks channel to adapter - TY for info & logical lead

Comment: What makes you believe they're anything other than client devices (cell phones for example) looking for WiFi?

Comment: Have you activated option `-a` ("Filter unassociated clients")?

Answer (score 1):

not sure how public we are trying to make the solutions, but figure this will be a buried question soon anyway once answered....but i greatly appreciate the help given and found and would like to return favor only way i know.

try change attacker MAC to same as victim router MAC then begin attack
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/72538 (related to problems w/deauth)
    (1)So do this:

```
    Disable mon0.
    Shut down wireless interface ifconfig wlan0 down (or whatever your interface is called).
    (my step) run: airmon-ng check -> kill NetworkManager PID (networkmanager fucks up hw ether mac change)
Set the attacker's MAC to your routers: ifconfig wlan0 hw ether TARGET_MAC.
    (this is where u do the monitor mode method)Reactivate interface, create new mon0 and do your deauth attack. It should work now. (Also make sure replay the deauth packet 3-4 times as for some reason sometimes a single death just won't work.)
```

(3)try When you enter monitor mode you can specify a channel like this: "airmon-ng start wlan0 x" where x is the channel number

(2)try alternative monitor mode method: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/135841

```
 ifconfig wlan0 down
 sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
 sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

This is can cause SIOCSIFHWADDR: Invalid argument error

```
 iwconfig wlan0 mode managed (to undo monitor mode & fix error)
```